# Forcing Redraw of flash content in IE 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, flash

Here's the situation:
I have an flash swf on a page loaded with object/embed tags.

```
<object width="565" height="300" >
  <param name="movie" value="/swf/Sample-Elf.swf">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  <embed src="/swf/Sample-Elf.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" width="565" height="300"></embed>
</object>
```

I need to be able to start/stop or reload this swf with purely javascript as I don't have access to the source swf file to add any actionscript.

I figured the easiest way to pull this off is by removing the element and replacing it forcing a redraw with would hince reload the swf movie. Though ie seams to cache the flash element and pretty much look over any updates I make to the embed/object tags and keeps right on going.

So how do I force IE to redraw/update a flash element on a page?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the javascript you used. 
I always had problems with browsers caching flash, especially IE because of it's stupid automatic huge cache settings.
So I have used a little trick of adding parameter after the flash filename like: 
         Sample-Elf.swf?v=0.1
When needed to force the browser to reload the file I was changing the parameter like: 
         Sample-Elf.swf?v=0.2
In your case you could put the actual time like parameter, so the file will be considered a brand new file on every load.
This helped me, but I was not using javascript to reload the flash in the content, so I am not sure it will help you. Maybe if you'll show the javascript I can help you more.